# How to load .txt file into an object array using >> overloading? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

This is my first time posting on this site so please spare me any mistakes/etiquette screw ups!

Basically I have a project due on Wednesday (yes, for a class). The code is to be written in C++ and it is a program that takes the following data members (as defined in a student class) from a .txt file listed below:

```
class Student
{
public: 
    //other functions such as add/edit/delete, etc... go here
private:
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int grade; //1 for Freshman, 2 for Sophmore, 3 for Junior, 4 for Senior
    int student_id;
    double credit_hours; //credit hours taken
    double GPA; //current GPA
};
```

I have also attached the .txt file below. Basically I have to read in the .txt file into an array of that class type, i.e. an object of the Student class. Our teacher said we could assume that the maximum size of the array was [100] students. I have tried several variations of a readFile() function but none have worked. I know I have to overload the >> operator to work with the Student class but I'm not sure how to do this. She suggested a friend function?

Here is the .txt file called "StudentRecords.txt" saved in the same directory as the other .cpp file.

```
Harry
Smith
2
11121321
100
3.8
Mary
Jones
1
43213843
56
3.1
Nicolas
Dodsworth
4
54219473
120
2.3
J.Alfred
Prufrock
4
83746321
122
4.0
T.S.
Eliot
1
99999999
126
4.0
Charlotte
Webb
3
44443333
98
3.8
Don
Juan
1
12345678
56
1.2
John
Smith
2
54234876
66
2.85
Darth
Vader
2
87623450
49
2.55
3
CPO
4
33333333
100
4.0
Emily
Dickinson
3
23456120
110
3.6
James
Buchanan
1
5640012
30
2.23
Carl
Rove
1
12995425
28
1.6
Marie
Curie
4
88888888
96
3.5
Micky
Mouse
2
8222222
64
1.85
James
Madison
3
66633333
88
2.96
Dolly
Madison
3
53423445
84
3.24
Pepe
LePew
1
73737373
42
2.47
Homer
Simpson
4
7223344
105
1.03
Mary
Jones
1
09274726
28
2.92
Bloss
Sims
4
11111111
100
1.2
```

Thanks guys! I really appreciate your help. I don't really have a lot of experience with C++ mainly Python, so this would definitely be helping me out.

EDIT:

Code below. The read function is the last function:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class stdRecord
{
public:
    string studentID;
    string studentName;
    int courseCode;
    int creditPoint;
};

const int MAXRECORD = 100;

int menu();
void searchStudent(stdRecord[],int);
void showByCourse(stdRecord[],int);
//void showEligible(stdRecord[],int);
void showAll(stdRecord[],int);
void update(stdRecord[],int );
void add(stdRecord[],int *);
void deleteRecord(stdRecord[],int *);
void findCourses(stdRecord [],int );

int main()
{
    stdRecord stdRec[MAXRECORD]={"15000000","Joshua Andrew Smith", 3506, 240,"16666666", "Jack Williams", 3506, 180,"17000010", "Lily Jones", 3639, 110};
    int counter=3;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        choice=menu();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 0: cout<<"Bye for Now"<<endl;
            break;
            case 1: searchStudent(stdRec,counter);
            break;
            case 2:showByCourse(stdRec,counter);
            break;
            case 3://showEligible(stdRec,counter);
            break;
            case 4:showAll(stdRec,counter);
            break;
            case 5:update(stdRec,counter);
            break;
            case 6:add(stdRec,&counter);
            break;
            case 7:deleteRecord(stdRec,&counter);
            break;
        }
    }while(choice!=0);
    system("pause");
}

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout<<"0. Exit"<<endl
    <<"1. Search for a student"<<endl
    <<"2. List students enrolled in a course"<<endl
    <<"3. List students eligible to graduate"<<endl
    <<"4. List all students"<<endl
    <<"5. Update a student record"<<endl
    <<"6. Add a student record"<<endl
    <<"7. Delete a student record"<<endl    
    <<"Your choice ->";
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
}

void searchStudent(stdRecord stdRec[],int counter)
{
    string ID;
    cout<<"Enter the student ID to search-> ";
    getline(cin,ID);

    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        if(stdRec[i].studentID.compare(ID)==0)
        {
            cout<<"The record with the id is:"<<endl;
            cout<<"StudentID\tStudentName\tCourseCoce\tCreditPoint"<<endl;
            cout<<stdRec[i].studentID<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].studentName<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].courseCode<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].creditPoint<<endl;
            cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            return;
        }
    }
    char ch;
    cout<<"Not Found"<<endl;
    cout<<"Do you want search another record(Y/N)";
    cin>>ch;
    ch=tolower(ch);
    if(ch=='y')
    searchStudent(stdRec,counter);
    else
    {
    cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    }
}
void findCourses(stdRecord stdRec[],int counter)
{
    int courses[500];
    int coursecount=0;
    cout<<" Enter the course code {";
    bool found;
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        found=false;
        for(int j=0;j<coursecount;j++)
        {
            if(stdRec[i].courseCode==courses[j])
            {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    if(!found)
        courses[coursecount++]=stdRec[i].courseCode;
    }
    cout<<" Enter the course code {";
    for(int j=0;j<coursecount-1;j++)
        cout<<courses[j]<<", ";
    cout<<"or "<<courses[coursecount-1]<<"->";
}

void showByCourse(stdRecord stdRec[],int counter)
{
    int courseCode;
    findCourses(stdRec,counter);
    cin>>courseCode;
    cout<<"The student(s) enrolled in the course is(are):"<<endl;
    cout<<"StudentID\tStudentName\tCourseCoce\tCreditPoint"<<endl;
    int studentsCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        if(stdRec[i].courseCode==courseCode)
        {
            cout<<stdRec[i].studentID<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].studentName<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].courseCode<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].creditPoint<<endl;
            studentsCount++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"There is(are) "<<studentsCount<<" student(s) enrolled in the course."<<endl;
    cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}


void showEligible(stdRecord stdRec[],int counter)
{
    cout<<"The student(s) eligible to graduate is(are):"<<endl; 
    int studentsCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        if(stdRec[i].creditPoint>=240)
        {
            cout<<stdRec[i].studentID<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].studentName<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].courseCode<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].creditPoint<<endl;
            studentsCount++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"There is(are) "<<studentsCount<<" graduate student(s)."<<endl;
    cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}


void showAll(stdRecord stdRec[],int counter)
{
    cout<<"All students are listed below:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        cout<<stdRec[i].studentID<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].studentName<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].courseCode<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].creditPoint<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

void update(stdRecord stdRec[],int counter)
{
    char keepGoing;
    string ID;
    do
    {

        cout<<"Enter the student ID to update-> ";
        getline(cin,ID);
        bool flag=false;
        char choice;
        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            if(stdRec[i].studentID.compare(ID)==0)
            {
                cout<<"The record with the id is:"<<endl;                                         cout<<"StudentID\tStudentName\tCourseCoce\tCreditPoint"<<endl;
                cout<<stdRec[i].studentID<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].studentName<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].courseCode<<"\t"<<stdRec[i].creditPoint<<endl;
                cout<<"Enter y or Y to update the course code, others to keep the original one."<<endl;
                cin>>choice;
                if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                {
                    int courseCode;
                    findCourses(stdRec,counter);
                    cin>>courseCode;
                    stdRec[i].courseCode=courseCode;
                }
                cout<<"Enter y or Y to update the credit";
                cin>>choice;
                if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
                {
                    int credits;
                    cout<<"Enter Credit points";
                    cin>>credits;
                    stdRec[i].creditPoint=credits;
                }
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!flag)
        {
            cout<<"The record with the id "<<ID<<" not Found"<<endl;
        }
            cout<<"Do you want update another record(Y/N)";
            cin>>keepGoing;
            keepGoing=tolower(keepGoing);
    }while(keepGoing=='y');

    cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

void add(stdRecord stdRec[],int *counter)
{
    string studentID;
    string studentName;
    int courseCode;
    int creditPoint;
    cout<<"Enter Student ID :";
    cin>>studentID;
    bool flag=true;
    for(int i=0;i<*counter;i++)
    {
        if(stdRec[i].studentID.compare(studentID)==0)
        {
        flag=false;
        break;
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        stdRec[*counter].studentID=studentID;
        cout<<"Enter Student Name \n";
        cin >> studentName;
        stdRec[*counter].studentName=studentName;
        cout<<"Enter Course Code \n";
        cin >> courseCode;
        stdRec[*counter].courseCode=courseCode;
        cout << "Enter Credit Points \n";
        cin >> creditPoint;
        stdRec[*counter].creditPoint=creditPoint;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Student Id Exists"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Have completed the requested process."<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

void deleteRecord(stdRecord stdRec[],int *counter){}



void readIn(stdRecord stdRec[])
{
    ifstream file("StudentRecords.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        stdRecord stdRec[MAXRECORD];

        for(int i = 0; i < MAXRECORD; i++)
        {
            file >> stdRec[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you tried, and we can help you figure things out starting there

Comment: And what is not working in this case? Do you get an error or unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    //define and/or modify your own constructors here
    Student() {}

    friend istream& operator >>(istream &input, Student& student);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &output, const Student& student);//I gave you this as a BONUS

private:
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    int grade;
    int student_id;
    double credit_hours;
    double GPA;
};

istream& operator >>(istream &input, Student& student) {
    input   >> student.firstname
            >> student.lastname
            >> student.grade
            >> student.student_id
            >> student.credit_hours
            >> student.GPA;
    return input;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &output, const Student& student) {
    output  << student.firstname << " "
            << student.lastname << " "
            << student.grade << " "
            << student.student_id << " "
            << student.credit_hours << " "
            << student.GPA << "\n";
    return output;
}

int main() {
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("StudentRecords.txt", ios::in);

    if (!ifile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "There was an error opening the input file!\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    Student student;

    while(ifile >> student) {
        cout << student;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given the data you had, this outputs:

```
James Buchanan 1 5640012 30 2.23
Carl Rove 1 12995425 28 1.6
Marie Curie 4 88888888 96 3.5
Micky Mouse 2 8222222 64 1.85
James Madison 3 66633333 88 2.96
Dolly Madison 3 53423445 84 3.24
Pepe LePew 1 73737373 42 2.47
Homer Simpson 4 7223344 105 1.03
Mary Jones 1 9274726 28 2.92
Bloss Sims 4 11111111 100 1.2
```

As expected.

The only issue is that this code is for **one** student, not 100. But, you can do that - everything in moderation after all. All you have to do is create an array of `Student` objects, iterate over them and assign them values similar to how I did.